# How to play music and use the beat detector in vvvv

Tags: audio-streaming, beat-detection

does anyone knows how to listen the audio of a song while the beat detector is working with vvvv? Right now I can connect the output pin of the file stream node to the beat detector node and it works, also I can connect the output pin to the audio out node and listen to the song, but i can't do both simultaneously... is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you set up two stream nodes i believe. One to the beat detector, one to the audio out. Its odd, but that seems to be the way to do it. Have you checked F1 on the audio in or  stream node. It might have an example showing this.